# How to remove trailer of the packet in python using scapy

Tags: python, ethernet, scapy

I'm reading a pcap file in python using scapy which contains Ethernet packets that have trailer. How can I remove these trailers?

P.S: Ethernet packets can not be less than 64 bytes (including FCS).Network adapters add padding zero bytes to end of the packet to overcome this problem. These padding bytes called "Trailer". See [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Ethernet#Allowed_Packet_Lengths) for more information.

Comment: are you talking abt:
#USER_AGENT = ' (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

Comment: No. I means trailer of the packet in Ethernet header. `USER_AGENT` exists in HTTP header.

Comment: well why don't you use some proxy, I use TOR and I don't identify myself, (by uncomming that line ). so nothing seems to go through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no official way to remove it. This work on frames that have IPv4 as network layer protocol:

```
packet_without_trailer=IP(str(packet[IP])[0:packet[IP].len])
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use the upper layers and ignore the Ethernet layer:

`packet = eval(originalPacket[IP])`